# отправка запроса json через php+curl

Tags: php, json, curl

Есть необходимость отправить следующий хук:

```
 POST /hooks/fa63636975788d7/execute HTTP/1.1
 Host: some.host
 Content-Type: application/json

{
"name": "Тестовая задача",
"desc": "Данная задача создана через Hook и может быть удалена"
}
```

Накидал скрипт следующим образом :

```
<?php
$data='{"name": "Тестовая задача","desc": "Данная задача создана через Hook и может быть удалена"}';
$json=json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('https://some.host/hooks/fa63636975788d7cd80/execute'); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS,CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Доступа к логам сервера some.host нет, скрипт отрабатывает но на сервере заявка не падает, сам впервые использую cURL, подскажите рабочий ли этот вариант ?

Comment: Запилите свой test.host, шлите туда  и смотрите, что приходит

Answer (score 1):

Первый момент - Вы делаете json_encode уже строки json ([см. пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b0804c1c7ea089f5b69aa5e337442b5f113a1f5e)), и возможно сервер такой json не понимает.

Второй момент - Вы шлете и $data (curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);) и $json (curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$json);)

Попробуйте такой вариант

```
$json='{"name": "Test Case","desc": "This is test task"}';
$ch = curl_init('https://some.host/hooks/fa63636975788d7cd80/execute'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); //переключаем запрос в POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$json); //Это POST данные
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //Отключим проверку сертификата https
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); //из той же оперы
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

На первый взгляд ваш код рабочий, однако при запросе могут возникнуть ошибки которые надо выловить, попробуйте в вашем коде удалить `curl_exec` и `curl_close`  и  добавить данный кусок завершения `CURL` :

```
$Result = curl_exec($ch);
  $CURL_Error = curl_errno($ch);

  if ($CURL_Error > 0)
  {
    echo 'cURL Error: --'.$CURL_Error.'--<br>';
    $RetStr = false;
  }
  else
  {
    $RetStr = $Result;
  }

  curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Добавил, ошибок не выводиться при выполнение.

Comment: а что вы получаете на выходе?  если сделать var_dump($Result);

Comment: string(74) "��VJI,IT����QJ-*�/R�R��+K��L�O�O�T� ǧ�'e�d��!�(d��=�E"

Comment: перед вызовом CURL поставьте кодировку     header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8', true);    чтобы понять что вам возращает в ответе

Answer (score 0):

Надо было использовать всего лишь curl_setopt_array, всем спасибо за помощь!